# Image not showing on frontend after deleting rows from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table

Tags: magento-1.9, database, image

I have products that have images that were deleted from disk. I am trying to remove them from the database, but when I remove the non-existing image rows from the database, the images that ARE on disk no longer show (the placeholder image shows instead).

The weird part is, the image is still showing on the backend.

Re-indexing, clearing cache, chowning & chmoding, PHP memory is set to 1G. Nothing has worked.

Before I ran this code, all images (that existed on disk) were showing on the front-end just fine. After running this code, they no longer were.

Here is how I am removing the images:

```
 class ProductHelper
 {
    const IMAGE_DB_TABLE = 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery';

    public static function findImagesThatDoNotExist(callable $callback)
    {
        $stillHasResults = true;

        $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
            ->getConnection('core_read');

        $select = $read->select()
            ->from(['media' => static::IMAGE_DB_TABLE], '*')
            ->where('value_id > ?', $id = 0)
            ->limit(2);

        while ($stillHasResults) {
            $results = $read->fetchAll($select);

            if (empty($results)) {
                $stillHasResults = false;
            }

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $callback($result);
            }

            $id = array_pop($results)['value_id'];

            $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)
                ->where('value_id > ?', $id);

        }
    }
}


$mediaPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/catalog/product';

/** @var \Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql $write */
$write = Mage::getModel('core/resource')
    ->getConnection('core_write');

ProductHelper::findImagesThatDoNotExist(function ($result) use ($mediaPath, $write) {
    if (! file_exists($path = $mediaPath . $result['value'])) {
         $where = 'value_id=' . $result['value_id'];

        $write->delete(ProductHelper::IMAGE_DB_TABLE, $where);
    }
});
```